# Using csurf with react-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, csrf, react-server

I would like to add [csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) as an express middleware inside the [react-server](https://react-server.io/) for a universal app.

What I want to achieve is adding the csrf token to a hidden input in a form in the react component to maintain the same csrf protection flow a server-rendered website would provide, but within a SPA.

Is this technically possible within the react-server? If so, how can I pass the csrf token that is available in the response object to the react component via the page (ideally)?

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into the same problem and luckily happened to come across the solution here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1142

to use it just do:

```
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true, value: (req) => (req.cookies.csrfToken) }));
```

and then for every get request set a cookie with the csrf token:

```
res.cookie('csrfToken', req.csrfToken ? req.csrfToken() : null, { sameSite: true, httpOnly: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it seems to be a fairly generic solution so it may work in a react-server context as well.

Comment: I don't get what the point of this is though. If you're auto setting the token in every request, without receiving it from the client, its pretty much useless

Comment: I think that the custom `value` function that checks for the CSRF token shouldn't look inside the cookies, but in the body or in the header of the request, as per [default behaviour in the csurf docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf#value), otherwise checking the cookie lets the server prone to the CSRF attack you are trying to defend from!